# How to make dvisvgm output colors properly (wrong text color on dark background)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, svg, dvi, output, dvi-mode

Example code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[alignedleftspaceno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagecolor{black}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \path node[text=white]
            {%
                $%
                    \begin{aligned}
                        2\times 3=6
                    \end{aligned}
                $
            };

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Prior to typesetting above code in TeXworks editor I had navigated to `edit -> preferences -> typesetting -> processing tools -> XeLaTeX` and added argument `-no-pdf` to the top of the list (this is the only way I managed to get xdv file).

Then I ran dvisvgm from the command line to get svg file. The svg file displays black image which only when selected (using mouse) displays the text (meaning that the text was undesirably rendered in different, default, color than specified).

Comment: presumably there is an error in your input document but it is impossible to debug code that you can not see. Please add a complete small document to your question that people can run and debug.

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour. For simplicity, you can compile the above file with `latex` (instead of `xelatex -no-pdf`), so that what's generated is a `.dvi` file rather than a `.xdv` file. (There are more tools that process DVI files.) The behaviour of `dvisvgm` is the same in that case too.

Comment: Simpler MWE: `\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path node[text=blue] {a};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
` (Note that `dvisvgm` doesn't respect the text colour.)

Comment: Ti*k*Z stuff isn't generally rendered correctly to DVI though, is it? You need to compile to PDF for everything to work, was my understanding.

Comment: You need to use the `dvisvgm` driver for Ti*k*Z for this to stand a chance of working properly.

Comment: Try using `\textcolor{white}{...}` inside the node. `pgfsys-dvisvgm.def` sets the colour to `.` in what I suspect gets used to make text nodes (although I'm far from sure about this). That is, it uses the current colour i.e. black in your document. The effects of `text=<colour>` are always a bit unpredictable in edge cases (and SVG output is surely an edge case).

Comment: @cfr, using `\textcolor` makes the text white. It is now obvious that svg is not the best way to output TeX. By the way, the svg image is tiny and spacing is off compared to the original. What a let down.

Comment: Why did you think it would be 'the best way to output TeX'? There are more unlikely things, I admit, but only because the standard for likeliness is pretty low.

Comment: I think you should [report this](https://github.com/mgieseki/dvisvgm/issues) to the `dvisvgm` author; the tool is otherwise excellent and claims to be able to interpret most DVI specials, so it should be able to interpret this one too. If you don't report it I will. In my experimentation, using the `dvisvgm` driver from TikZ gave the *worst* output compared to any of the other drivers.

Comment: When compiling your example file, xelatex creates PDF specials which dvisvgm doesn't support yet. If you use the dvips driver by adding `\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvips.def}`, the result should look much better. @bp2017, what do you mean by "the spacing is off"? Depending on your SVG viewer you must call dvisvgm also with option `-n`.

Comment: cfr, one would think svg is the best way to output TeX in a webpage (that's the key point I forgot to mention; webpage) since svg is scalable (vector). @Martin, adding this driver doesn't make a difference of notice. Spacing of characters in resulting svg greatly differs from the pdf output.

Comment: @bp2017, I can't reproduce that. The SVG output looks exactly the same as the PDF version -- at least for your given example. You must define `\pgfsysdriver` before including package `tikz`. Also, ensure that you call dvisvgm with option `-n` or `-fwoff`, for example.

Comment: @Martin So the dvisvgm driver for Ti*k*Z oughtn't be used? I tried following the instructions in the manual, which didn't help at all.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR What are DVI specials? I know there are PS specials and PDF specials, but I didn't think DVI itself had specials. Note that you at least need to use an appropriate driver for PGF uinless dvisvgm really claims it can cope with anything. (And then you still need to make sure you use a driver which supports the features you need e.g. text nodes are not supported by all drivers properly.)

Comment: @cfr You're right; it's just a matter of terminology — by DVI specials I just meant "specials inserted into the DVI file" (for example PostScript specials or PDF specials), which are a no-op unless the program that reads the DVI file (the driver) has some special handling for the contents of that special. For example with the `dvips` route, PS specials are inserted into the DVI file, and then `dvips` uses them to generate the PS file. You know all this already; am just saying it explicitly here for clarity/completeness for anyone else who may read this. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR The comment above by Martin, I think, says dvisvgm doesn't support PDF specials. If so, then it is not a bug that the OP's document fails as that is going to write the wrong kind of specials to the DVI, I think. (At least, it certainly isn't obvious that's not what is happening, especially given that it seems to work OK for Martin.)

Comment: @bp2017, the dvisvgm driver of TikZ seems to be less complete than the one for dvips. That's probably why it creates unsatisfying results in your case. Since dvisvgm supports PostScript specials, you can use the dvips driver instead if the other one fails.